# convert GMT to PST and then to unixtimestamp in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-datetime

I've a GMT time-stamp in "2018-02-22T14:09:40.639GMT" format. which need to be converted to PST and then to unixtimestamp.

Can anyone give the quick solution for this.

Comment: What did your own search deliver?

Comment: Need to get some information lying between two unix-timestamps. For that I require this to convert to that format.

Comment: It's already clear. What did your own search deliver?

Comment: yeah.. Thanks Psytho. I got it.